# Connecting Monitor via HDMI->DVI Cable does not work

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

like many other users here, I got a lot of trouble connecting my pi to external monitors.
It connects flawlessly via HDMI to my TV. However, it does not work with my two DVI-D input monitors.
I tried every possible combination configuration of the /boot/config.txt but still they won't work.

I am connection through a HDMI->DVI (24+5!) adapter. Could this be the problem?
I guess 24+5 means DVI-I Dual-Link which should be working fine with my DVI-D Single-Link cable when it is connected to a DVI-Output. 
But does it also work when the original output is HDMI?
So would buying a dedicated HDMI->DVI-D do the job?

Thank you!

Comment: This should not be a problem, regardless of the adapter. I use both kinds with my monitors. Dual link would only work for high resolutions, which AFAIK the Pi doesn't support. You shouldn't need any special settings. Are you sure the monitors are DVI-D and not DVI-A? Can you list the supported modes on another computer. What is in /boot/config.txt?

Comment: The monitor supports DVI-D and was tested on a PC. On that PC also the setup with the HDMI converter works. I tried several combinations in the config file, activated the safe mode and set the HDMI-mode to 35, which is 1280*1024 on 60 hertz. Using  /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT gives me all right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having bought a HDMI->DVI (18+1) cable everything is working fine without any changes in the config.txt

Comment: My guess would be that most likely the adaptor you had was simply faulty.