# Combine Raspberry Pi and a PC on a single monitor - using one switch

Tags: hardware, windows

I want to help a friend with the following problem:
Interested in combining a Raspberry Pi (HDMI connection) and regular PC (DVI-D?) to a singal DVI-D that will connect to a monitor.
I would like to connect it to a single PC screen with DVI-D connection.
the solution must have a "switch" that I will be able to choose if I will use the Raspberry Pi or the PC with the monitor.

Same Question about keyboard and mouse - 
using one set of wireless keyboard and mouse, I want to change the connection with a switch from to Raspberry Pi to regular PC.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a KVM-switch and for the Pi an additional HDMI-to-DVI adaptor for the Pi.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch):

> A KVM switch (with KVM being an abbreviation for "keyboard, video and mouse") is a hardware device that allows a user to control multiple computers from one or more[1] sets of keyboards, video monitors, and mice.

See [here](https://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#HDMI-.3EDVI-D_cables) for what kind of adaptor to look for - HDMI to DVI-D cables, or HDMI cables with an DVI-D adapters should work though, see also [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36785/19949). Some posts on the internet claim that it might be necessary to tweak the Pi's config (`/boot/config.txt`) to make DVI-D work properly, e.g. [here](https://elinux.org/RPiconfig) setting **hdmi_drive** to choose between HDMI and DVI modes:

> hdmi_drive=1 Normal DVI mode (No sound)
>
> hdmi_drive=2 Normal HDMI mode (Sound will be sent if supported and enabled)

More often than not displays provide more than one input which would allow to connect both the Pi and the PC directly to the monitor (as an alternative).

Comment: Thanks!!
Will this do the job?
https://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-2-Port-Desktop-B004-DUA2-K-R/dp/B0011E823Q/ref=sr_1_12?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1512838168&sr=1-12&keywords=DVI+D+USB+KVM

Comment: I cannot tell but with this price tag attached it might be cheaper to go for another keyboard and mouse... and switch the monitor directly if it offers two appropriate inputs.